# Building divs in JS or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've got an application that takes user form data and sends that to an external php file via ajax.  The php file sends back rows from our database, which is then parsed in JS to generate some div strings and append them to the page.  Is this bad practice? Should I be generating the divs in php and returning those instead?

Comment: I typically like to create the divs in the PHP file that is being called via ajax. Each to their own I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might end up being closed due to it being somewhat opinion based. However, in my experience it is best to generate UI things on the UI. So, creating your HTML in JS is a good thing. It keeps all of your view code out of the code that is fetching and returning your data. You could refer to it as the single responsibility principle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) in that PHP is responsible for getting the data, and JS is responsible for showing the data.

An example of where this ends up being important is "what if you need to use this data on another page?". If the display format is different, do you then start appending query parameters to tell PHP which way to build the divs.. or do you simply have the page that consumes the data build it how the page wants the data to be displayed? (Hint: you should chose the latter option)

Comment: I know it's a bit opinion based, but as someone who is relatively new to php and js I was wondering if there was any language specific reasons why that was a bad idea.  The entire reason I posted this is because I'm trying to follow SRP, but I wasn't sure if that was the optimal/expected way to do this as I may not be the person who ends up maintaining the code.

Comment: No worries - I was basically just trying to get across the point that there may be a lot of opinions on the subject.

Comment: Haha, isn't that always the way of things? Thanks again for the good points.

Comment: Oh, and no - there's really no reason to mash the things together except for really, really weird and off track circumstances.. so much so that I'm not sure I could come up with a good one.

Comment: Or you can use PHP views to render the HTML using PHP, it still keeps the logic separate

Comment: @ChrisB true, though I suppose it comes down to "what is the call for". If the call is really just to get some data to display to a user, it seems to make more sense to have the final view render it, rather than have a view generate something for a view. Why add the extra step, I suppose. Especially since it's just as easy to do it in JS as it is in PHP, and should require less bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not bad practice. Many javascript libraries allow you to generate HTML from data using templates. Also, just sending data reduces your application's bandwidth consumption. However, generating the div's server-side would (obviously) reduce client-side computation and code size. In other words, it depends on your situation.

Answer (score 1):

It's not bad practice for PHP to render your view (I think that might partly be why it was created!), but within your PHP code it is bad practice to combine code that deals with database fetch operations with code that deals with your view. These should be nicely segregated.